# Manually Setting rowCount in GWT DataGrid with a ListDataProvider does not work?

Tags: gwt, datagrid, gwt-rpc

I am using a `DataGrid` together with a `ListDataProvider` to display various row data in my application. For most cases, it was fine to fetch everything from the server at once.
Now, it appears to be necessary to fetch data on pagination steps. This means, my RPC call returns 10 items each time and the total count of possible results.

The total count is used to setup the attached `SimplePager` by manually calling `datagrid.setRowCount(totalCount, true)` after having set the row data. *After* is important here, 
because setRowData also triggers a setRowCount call with the concrete number of items (always 10 in my case).

The problem is that after having set the row count manually, another participant, a `ScheduledCommand` triggers a `flushCommand` which in turn triggers a `setRowCount` call which 
sets the count back to 10. The consequence: the pager shows 1-10 of 10 and the pager controls are disabled.

How can I enforce a certain rowCount even if the `ListDataProvider` only has 10 items each time?

You might suggest to use an `AsyncDataProvider`. However, there already is a quite complex generic design (`AbstractTablePresenter<DTO, ...>` implementing all the logic to fetch data and push it to a generic display) 
which is backed by ListDataProviders. Hard to explain, but actually, I would prefer keep using the `ListDataProvider`.

Comment: How you handle the next page request?

Comment: My presenter is registered as handler for rangeChangeEvents and triggers RPC calls which load the data of the current page.

Answer (score 0):

For my usecase, the easiest fix was to subclass my `AbstractTablePresenter` for the on-demand case and use an `AsyncDataProvider` which brings all the features I need. The hurts concerning my design was less heavy than expected (knocking on my shoulders ;-) ).

Tried to subclass `ListDataProvider` first but the relationship of data, rowCount, rowCountEvents and the attached pager objects is so manifold that you would end up overriding most of the methods of `ListDataProvider` and your pager implementation.